What is wrong with the bookmarklet that is supposed to delete some element on specific page?
The following bookmarklet should remove a specific element from web-page opened in Chrome (I plan to use it on single webpage only, so there would be no need for a more general solution; also, I am interested in solution that would not be run automatically, hence the bookmarklet):
javascript: function run() { var r = "/html/body/div/div[1]"; var e = document.getElementByXpath(r); e.parentNode.removeChild(e) }; run();

It does not work, though.
Full disclosure: I have never written a single line of JS code before (so I would appreciate both explanation of what is wrong and correction), the bookmarklet is a simplified variant of the one suggested in the accepted answer of this thread.

Please edit your question and provide debugging details. "It does not work" is not specific. What steps did you take to debug this and what did you find in that debugging? Also, what exactly do you expect the code to do? i.e. what specific element is supposed to be removed? Please add in those details (including the HTML so we can see the element) as well.

@devlincarnate Well, let me put it this way, the bookmarklet execution results in no visible changes on the page. The expected result would be deleting the element with the given XPath (variable r), so I expect it to vanish from the page. I am not sure what is the debugging process for JS (as I said I never used this language in the past, but the code looks logical to me, obviously, there is something subtle I am missing). As for the html-code, I can't post it here, sorry, it belongs to the client and the page can't be accessed openly (anyway, I can assure you the Xpath is correct).

document.getElementByXpath isn’t a standard browser function.  See related

@James Frankly, what is written in the thread you referred to is too complicated for me (but thank you for the tip). That being said, I tried to replace the definition for the variable r with the following line var r = document.evaluate("/html/body/div/div[1]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);. Unfortunately, it has not worked, I still see no changes on the page resulted of running the updated bookmarklet code.

We aren't going to be able to identify the issue without an MRE or debugging details because we have no way to determine what the cause of the problem is. Debugging JS is not some tighly held secret behind layers of security: you can employ your Google-fu to research the basics. console.log() and your browser's developer tools (specifically, the console, network and DOM inspection tabs) are likely going to be helpful in your debugging.

In your debugging, look for errors. Also verify you're correctly targeting the DOM element you want to remove.

Also, to simplify your debugging: you could set aside the bookmarklet and just work on debugging the JS until you know it's targeting the right DOM element and not producing any errors. Then go back to incorporating that into a bookmarklet.

You could try this:
javascript: { try { document.querySelector('body > div > div:nth-child(1)').remove() } catch {} }

Allow me to explain the code:
javascript: {
 try {
  document.querySelector('body > div > div:nth-child(1)').remove();
 } catch {}
}

First, we replace document.getElementByXpath() because the document doesn't have that function. Instead of an XPath, we'll use CSS selectors. CSS selectors are like an XPath, but they look different -- and you can do more with them (like selecting multiple elements).

Your XPath was "/html/body/div/div[1]"
The CSS selector looks very similar: body > div > div:nth-child(1)

That selector will look for every element that is the first child of a div in the body element. To limit it to one (the first one it finds) we use `document.querySelector()'. Using that will select only the first one found.

If you want to find every element that matches that, you would use document.querySelectorAll() and loop through each element found.
Incidentally, that code could look something like this:
javascript: {
 for(var element of document.querySelectorAll('body > div > div:nth-child(1)')) {
  element.remove();
 }
}


Finally, why use the try catch block? A try...catch statement basically just says, if this code fails, do what I want with the error. In this case, catch is empty so we're just saying that we don't want anything to happen if there's an error.
Hopefully this information is useful!

It works like a charm! Thank you for the code and special thanks for the explanation. It is my pleasure to accept it as the answer.
